# adding a button on android listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I have get the data from local DB and display it in a `ListView` and I had a custom row with button

main.xml will contain `ListView` only

**custom-row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
style="@color/background_gradient_start"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:alpha="0.6"
android:background="@color/background_gradient_start"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewFlightNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewCodes"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewCodes"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCodes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="#3b3974"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:text="Share"
            android:textColor="#f1ecef" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

so under on Create

```
String [] fromFiledName =new String[]{db.KEY_CODE};

int[] toViewIDs=new int[]{R.id.textViewCodes};

SimpleCursorAdapter myCurAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, //context
        R.layout.listview_row_codes,
        cursor,
        fromFiledName,
        toViewIDs
        );


// set addapter to list view
ListView mylistPRN=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.codeslist);
mylistPRN.setAdapter(myCurAdapter);

mylistPRN.setAdapter(myCurAdapter);

mylistPRN.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, PromoCodeActivity2.class);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
       //intent.putExtra(PromoCodeActivity.requestString, httpRequestString);
        //getItemAtPosition(position);
        Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share code "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("code")));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
        //startActivity(intentD);


    }
});
```

The code is working and when I click on the list view item  it open for sharing but I need it to open when the button is clicked as currently I tried to link the button but I couldn't. Any help

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do add following two lines to your buttons xml

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Then inside adapter getView method attach onclickListener to this button and you are done. Currently there is no listener attached to button in row.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `onItemClickListner` as you are not clicking on the list Items, rather you have to set the `onClickListner` on buttons in your getview method

something like this this

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelistlayout, null, true);
    Button yourBtn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.your_btn_id);

   yourBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Do your work here
        }
    });
    return rowView;

}
```

Also set following properties on your button

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: every time i put this method after onCreate it shows error and i have to remove @override and it cant see the context

Comment: you should not place it after the onCreate. you have to make an custom class extending the BaseAdapter, for more details please visit http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ check out the 2. Custom ArrayAdapter example